# How to resize images according to position

Tags: windows-phone

I am developing windows phone app.
My photos and their title are coming from Facebook.
Problem: first photo should be larger than other
and all other are in small size where 2 photos in one line.
And each photo should overlay with its name at below it. 
how to change the size and how to add text?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Image control (whether in XAML or code behind) to display the images, then you can set height and width on the control itself. In your case you know that you always want the first image to be larger than others, so set the height/width property of the Image control accordingly.

For overlay, you can use a Grid and either (a) set the correct margin on the Image and the TextBlock to make them overlay, or (b) set the vertical alignment property on the controls to make them overlay.

Something like this should work (with your actual values):